# How to do rotation on images saved on EC2 instance using react and then save the orientation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am saving various images grouped as albums (Kind of gallery app) on my server inside a static folder. Now after saving them I developed a web-app using react to show all the albums and then pictures. Now problem comes when the user wants to change the orientation of image. If we want to rotate an image then it should be rotated and then should be saved with same orientation on my server (original image needs to be replaced). Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Use a `canvas` element for your image manipulations, and then you can easily save it as an image. Finally, it should be trivial to update it on the server (design perhaps a node/express backend to handle the requests).

Comment: @A.J.Uppal I have already a backend using node/express for serving static folder. I was thinking how can I use canvas to get meta config after rotation and save it back to the static folder.